# Android Gradle Settings Plugin Not Found

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have multi module project in Android.And have recently migrated to Android Gradle Plugin Version 8.0

I am trying to apply new feature of applying global configuration for all the modules, using the new [Android gradle settings plugin.](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#settings-plugin) At the time of writing this answer it is not supported in kotlin dsl.

I tried applied the settings plugin like below in groovy.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.settings'
```

But it always throws below error.

> - Exception is:
>   org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.settings'] was not found in any of the following sources:
>   Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
>   Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

Not sure what I am missing.

My settings.gradle file.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.settings'
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "example"
include(":app")
include(":my-module")
```

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem (I also came here looking for an answer), but the configuration (and the plugin declaration) should be in `settings.gradle`, not `build.gradle` as per https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#settings-plugin

Comment: That was a typo here. Updated, Thanks.

I actually tried applying the plugin in settings.gradle only.

Comment: How about this solution? I solved the same problem with it: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/12thx5y/anyone_tried_the_new_comandroidsettings_plugin/jp2tgix/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Answer (score 0):

It clearly tells what's the issue is:

> plugin dependency must include a version number for this source

Thus

```groovy
pluginManagement {
...
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.settings' version '8.2.0'
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
...
}
```

---

<sup>FYI: you can find all the supported properties by the plugin [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/mirror-goog-studio-main/build-system/gradle-settings-api/previous-gradle-apis/).</sup>

<sup>Currently `targetSdk` isn't supported and there's already an issue opened for it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/317358817).</sup>